# How can I use setAttribute() with class name

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, html-helper

I have the following htmlhelper line:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "LeadDetails", new {@class = "detailsLink", id = item.user_id, urlfrom = "ManageDeposits" })
```

on `urlform` I want to pass the current url using javascript.

I do not know what the specific ActionLink's id is so I decided to use class name `detailsLink`

However when I use: `const det = document.getElementByName("detailsLink");`
I cannot use the `setAttribute()` function.

Are there any alternatives to use `setAttribute()` by getting the element using class name instead of id?

Answer (score 2):

Try `document.getElementsByClassName("detailsLink")[0]` to get your element by class name, but be sure that your class name is unique (check that there is only one tag using class="detailsLink", otherwise you might need to change the number 0 by order)